# Proving: If $|A\times B| = |A\times C|$, then $|B|=|C|$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Prove or disprove:

If $A\times B\sim A\times C$, then $B\sim C$.

("$\sim$": "numerically equivalent" / "has the same cardinality as")

What bijection/counterexample should I use to prove/disprove it?

Comment: Hint: Do you know of a non-empty set $A$ with $|A\times A| = |A|$?

Comment: @Tobias: Why non-empty? (This question is usually given before a proof that $|\Bbb N|=|\Bbb{N\times N}|$.)

Comment: Proof requires further assuming that $A,B,C$ are finite.

Comment: @hardmath: Additional assumptions are required.

Comment: It was only stated that A, B and C are sets. Though you may be right. @hardmath

Comment: @AsafKaragila:  Okay, finiteness and $A$ nonempty are sufficient.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Hmm, not sure how I managed to mention non-empty and not think one step further.

Comment: Assuming that $|A|\leq |B|$ and $|A|\leq |C|$ should also be sufficient.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If we assume the sets are non-empty and $X \sim Y$ means there is a bijection $\phi : X \to Y,$ won't it be sufficient?

Comment: @Krish: You will also need some finiteness condition.

Comment: @Guest What is the exact question: the one from the title ($\;|A \times B| = |A \times C| \implies |B|=|C|\;$), or the one from the question itself ($\;A \times B \sim A \times C \implies B \sim C\;$)?  The former is only meaningful for finite sets, or if you're clear about what kind of arithmetic you use for infinities.  The latter works also for infinite sets, and is usually bijection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** You are asked to divide $|A|\cdot|B|=|A|\cdot|C|$ by $|A|$. Can you think of $A$ such that $|A|$ is a number that cannot be reduced from both sides of the equation?

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A=\mathbb{N}$. Now take $B$ and $C$ any different, finite, non-empty sets. Actually it seems that you can take $A$ any infinite set, but for this one I'm not sure.