# Do an infinite set and its double have the same cardinality?

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, axiom-of-choice

My question was inspired by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1096470/191910).

Suppose $A$ is an infinite set. Does its double, $A\times\{0,1\}$, always have the same cardinality?

In my head I quickly spotted a simple proof that the answer is yes if we assume Axion of choice / Zorn's lemma. I have stumbled upon a couple of related questions, but the question looks so simple that I would like it answered *without* assuming AC.

Comment: If you want to link to a specific answer, you can find the address if you look at "share" directly underneath the answer.

Comment: Thanks, @HansLundmark, I've edited my post.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/393196/the-relationship-of-frak-mm-m-to-ac?rq=1

Comment: Thanks, @OohAah. Rather interesting. I'll have to read about Dedekind-finite sets.